# InvalidOperationException "different ObjectContext objects" when loading new DbContext

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a winforms application with a long running EF6 DbContext. It's a database first edmx model with lazy loading enabled. The context is created by business logic, it is private and the access to the collections of items is through business logic. Business logic is available through a single instance object called DataBridge.

I'm simulating a failure of the database by disconnecting the network bridge on the VM that hosts SQL Server, and trying to deal with switching to a backup. After I dispose of the context and create a new one I try reloading the data and I get the InvalidOperationException when I try to load one particular list... "The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects."

The following are cutouts from the BL and from the main form where this is happening:

**EDIT added 'Context' proeprty**

```
public class DataBridge
{
    private static DataBridge _staticBridge;

    private PPIEntitiesCtx _commonContext;

    private DataBridge()
    {
        _commonContext = new PPIEntitiesCtx(ConnectionTools.PrimaryDB);
        _commandEx = new CommandExecutor();
    }


    public static DataBridge Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_staticBridge == null)
                _staticBridge = new DataBridge();

            return _staticBridge;
        }
    }

    internal PPIEntitiesCtx Context
    {
        get
        {
            return _commonContext;
        }
    }

    public void SelectDB(string connectionStringName)
    {
        _commonContext.Dispose();
        _commonContext = new PPIEntitiesCtx(ConnectionTools.GetConnectionString(connectionStringName));
    }

    public MemberBL GetMemberBL()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_memberBL == null)
                _memberBL = new MemberBL(this);
            return _memberBL;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public WorkLogBL GetWorkLogBL()
    {
        if (_workLogBL == null)
            _workLogBL = new WorkLogBL(this);

        return _workLogBL;
    }
```

Here are excerpts from Form1

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _dataBridge = DataBridge.Instance;
        _memberLogic = _dataBridge.GetMemberBL();
        _workLogLogic = _dataBridge.GetWorkLogLogic();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // test connection
        // login
        LoadData();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
            MemberBindingSource.DataSource = _memberLogic.GetBindingList();
            // more bindings cut out 

            // Exception happens in the BL called from here
            workLogBindingSource.DataSource = _workLogLogic.GetBindingList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException(ex);
        }
    }

    private void SelectDB()
    {
        // Show dialog to select new DB 
        // (selects a connection string name from app.config)
        SelectDatabase frm = new SelectDatabase();
        frm.ShowDialog();
        if (frm != null && frm.selectedItem != null && frm.selectedItem.Length > 0)
        {
            _dataBridge.SelectDB(frm.selectedItem); // drops and creates a new context
            LoadData();
        }
    }
```

Here is the point in worklog BL where the exception is thrown

```
public class WorkLogBL : BaseBL, IBusinessLogic<WorkLog>
{
    public WorkLogBL(DataBridge dataBridge)
    {
        _dataBridge = dataBridge;
    }

    public BindingList<WorkLog> GetBindingList()
    {
        try
        {
            _dataBridge.Context.WorkLogs
                .OrderByDescending(wl => wl.Year)
                .ThenByDescending(wl => wl.Month)
                .Load();

            return _dataBridge.Context.WorkLogs.Local.ToBindingList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how much help the stack trace will be, it appears to be truncated...

```
"The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects."
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.ValidateContextsAreCompatible(RelatedEnd targetRelatedEnd)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Add(IEntityWrapper wrappedTarget, Boolean applyConstraints, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean allowModifyingOtherEndOfRelationship, Boolean forceForeignKeyChanges)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.PerformAdd(IEntityWrapper wrappedOwner, RelatedEnd relatedEnd, IEntityWrapper entityToAdd, Boolean isForeignKeyChange)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.PerformAdd(IList`1 entries)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.DetectChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(Boolean force)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_Local()
at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.get_Local()
at BusinessLogic.WorkLogBL.GetBindingList() in E:\Reliance\Projects\PCRS\PPI\PPI_DEV\BusinessLogic\WorkLogBL.cs:line 72
```

Line 72 is the line with GetBindingList()

So since the context is disposed and a new one is being reloaded, how could two objects be from different contexts? Will the objects being bound to controls on the form prevent the context from being disposed?
I tried to manually detach all items before disposing the context but that made things worse. The forms were trying to update all their contents as things were being removed.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm out of things to try.
TIA,
Mike

Comment: Can you add the code of Context property ?

Comment: I added the Context property. It's just a getter for the _commonContext within DataBridge. It's scope is internal so that only BL can get to it.

Comment: Since the code is not complete I don't know if it's related. The DataBridge is implemented as a singleton, be aware that this implementation is not thread safe. Multiple threads can enter the 'if (_staticBridge == null)' test at the same time causing multiple instances of the class to be instantiated.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the idea. I had thought of that and tried two ideas. I changed it to a static constructor where the item is created on startup, and I wrote to the output window from the constructor. It only appears once.
Do you have a solution to the thread safety issue? Is there a thread safe single instance pattern?